# orgmode capture template

Tags: org-mode

I am a newbie at emacs lisp and was looking for some assistance.

I am trying to use a capture template from a file.
Here is relevant code:

```
(setq base-capture-template (concat (file-name-as-directory capture-template-directory) "base_tpl.txt"))
(setq org-capture-templates
  (quote (("w" "work" entry (file+headline org-tasks-file "WORK") (file base-capture-template) :kill-buffer t)))
```

When I try the template, I get an error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, base-capture-template`.

Is there a way to convert the symbol `base-capture-template` such that it corresponds to the expected type?

Thanks.

-gyro

Comment: As you have written it, there is a missing closing paren for the second `setq`: either add it or use the `'(...)` shorthand instead of `(quote (...))`. Some other relevant code is missing: what is `capture-template-directory`? What is `org-tasks-file`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but I don't think you can have two different target specifications for the same entry: either `file+headline` or `file` but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SX (emacs).

Try this:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  `(("w" "work" entry (file+headline org-tasks-file "WORK") 
    (file ,base-capture-template) :kill-buffer t)))
```

Explanation: the back-quote allows you to mostly quote but evaluate the bits that have a comma in front.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the help, Fran. I would upvote your response, but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: I think you can accept the answer though!  (And glad this helped.)